# SIMOGEO Filemanager: how change upload folder?

Tags: file-manager

I have this Filemananager in

/lib/external/filemanager

(full path of my website is `/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.it/httpdocs/lib/external/filemanager`)

I can only upload on the default directory (`/lib/external/filemanger/userfiles`) but i need upload in (in [bracket] the full path)

```
[/var/www/vhosts/xxxx.it/httpdocs]/images/users
```

I played for about an hour with the

```
"serverRoot": true,
"fileRoot": false,
```

changing in

```
"serverRoot": true,
"fileRoot": 'images/users',
```

or in

```
"serverRoot": false,
"fileRoot": '/images/users',
```

or adding also the full path (`/var/www......`)

But without success. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json wants the double quote, not single quote ..... :(

So answer is simple

```
"serverRoot": true,
"fileRoot": "images/users",
```